# How do I "unscope" an edit path and/or action in Rails 3?

Tags: view, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2, default-scope, url-helper

Currently I'm working on a simple Rails 3 web application with devise. When users sign up an `Account` is created. This the essence of the Account model:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Authority::UserAbilities

  # Callbacks
  after_create do |account|
      account.create_person
      account.add_role :owner, account.person
  end

  has_one :person, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And the essence of the Person model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  default_scope where(published: true)
end
```

As you can see a person (which basically is a user profile) is created after the creation of an account, the default value of `published` is `false`. After signing up the user is signed in and redirected to the home page, which contains `edit_person_path(current_account.person)`.

After setting the `default_scope` for Person a `Routing Error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"people", :id=>nil}` was thrown because of `edit_person_path(current_account.person)`.

My solution to this was to change `edit_person_path(current_account.person)` into `edit_person_path(Person.unscoped { current_account.person} )`.

The issue that I'm having now is that although the page is rendering fine, when I click on the edit link the following exception is raised:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PeopleController#edit
Couldn't find Person with id=126 [WHERE "people"."published" = 't']
```

**What's the best way to temporarily unscope the edit action, should I do this in `PeopleController#edit`?**

Comment: So after writing this up I realized unscoping in `PeopleController#edit` with `@person = Person.unscoped.find(params[:id])` works fine... but maybe has someone else has another technique.